# We have a corrupted Key store for the Android App and hence cannot publish the updates to the existing App. What is the workaround?

Tags: android, keystore, updates

There's an existing App into the Android Market and due to some reasons our existing Key store has got corrupted and hence we aren't able to publish the updates for the same. How do we workaround this problem?

Comment: i don't think you can! see http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Android+Market/thread?tid=160ad25d6928dc43&hl=en

Answer (score 2):

You have to make a new keystore for the application and publish it as a new one.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, if you have lost the key there is nothing you can do about it except publishing a new application

Comment: Martin thanks for clearing my fears. How do we inform the existing App Users about the new update available?

Comment: The only way I can instantly think of is going to your "Edit Application" page at the android market and add a note on top of the description text that there is a new app available - unfortunately this will not inform the existing users (as requested by you). Doing so is hardly possible IMHO since you are not able to modify the application any more